# What RTOS is best for working on the same PC with Windows?

Tags: windows, rtos

What RTOS is best for working on the same PC with Windows?

I know about RTX and INtime, but have not used them.  Are there any others?  Which one is your favorite and why?

Answer (score 2):

I would try eCos. It is runs on the i386, is free, has great tool support, and includes board support packages ready made.

Answer (score 1):

QNX is used extensively for aircraft electronics.  However, pretty much any OS will run inside of Windows using VMWare or dual-booting though.

Comment: I don't think virtualization of a realtime OS will still result in guaranteed timing...

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to have a lot of fun with real-time systems, why not play around with Ubuntu's real-time patch and turn an old computer you have into a real-time desktop or use virtualbox or something of course. Here is a link you will find useful in getting it setup:

http://viswanathj.wordpress.com/2011/02/15/real-time-operating-system-installation-on-ubuntu-linux/

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuStudio/RealTimeKernel

This works with 10.04 LTS , x86 architectures with Intel, AMD & ARM processors, etc.

Cheers!!